# How to get the squared norm of each vector from a Table?

Tags: list-manipulation, vector, linear-algebra

This question is certainly very basic, but I don't get it!  How can I make a table of all the squared norms from this table?

```
pos = Flatten[Table[{x - u, y - v}, {u, -2, 2, 1}, {v, -2, 2, 1}], 1]
```

This code output a list of 25 2d vectors, like this:

> {{2 + x, 2 + y}, {2 + x, 1 + y}, {2 + x, y}, {2 + x, -1 + y}, ...}

Now, I need to get a simple table of 25 scalar elements (dot product) like this:

> {(2 + x)^2 + (2 + y)^2,  (2 + x)^2 + (1 + y)^2,  (2 + x)^2 + y^2,  (2 +
> x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2, ...}

I can get each element of this list with the following, where n = 1, 2, ..., 25 is a variable:

```
pos[[n]].pos[[n]]
```

But how can I get the full table itself?  I could make this: `Table[pos[[n]].pos[[n]], {n, 1, 25}]` but I don't think it's very elegant (feels like an "hack").

Comment: What don't you understand? This is really easy with `Map` and `Norm` e.g: `Map[Norm[#]^2 &, pos, {2}] /. Abs -> Identity`. The `/. Abs -> Identity` just gets rid of the `Abs`. If you don't want a matrix, then just `Flatten` the result.

Comment: Would `Table[(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}]~Flatten~1` work then? Or `Function[ {u, v}, (x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2] @@@ Tuples[Range[-2, 2], {2}]`?

Comment: Yep, that would be much simpler.  I'll play with it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simplify[Norm[#]^2 & /@ Flatten[pos, 1], _ ∈ Reals]

(* Out: 
{(2 + x)^2 + (2 + y)^2, (2 + x)^2 + (1 + y)^2, ..., (-2 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2}
*)
```

1. Your Table results is a 2D matrix of vectors, so it first needs to be flattened intro a 1D list of vectors, since you want a flat list of 25 numbers.
2. You want the squared norm of each element (`Norm[#]^2&`) so we `Map` that function over each element of the list.
3. Mathematica assumes that all variables are complex if not told otherwise, so you have to tell it that it can simplify e.g. `Abs[2 + x]^2` into `(2 + x)^2`. We do that using `Simplify` with the assumption that any variable (`_`) is `Real`.

Comment: Why the _ in Reals?  And why the Simplify? Do I need these?  Can you write this code in another way that I could understand instead of #?  I'll need this table in a sum, in another part of my code.

Comment: @Cham Have you tried removing each pieces step by step and seeing what happens?

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand what I'm doing, if I remove things here and there, and the error messages aren't very helpful.  The &/ and _ aren't my way of coding Mma, it feels to cryptic.

Comment: Adding the Flatten in the definition of pos helps a lot.  Then I could use **pos[[n]].pos[[n]]**, which is a nice step forward.

Comment: @Cham You need to bite that bullet at some point. `Map` (`/@`),  `Slot`s (`#`) and pure functions `&` are critical components of effective Mathematica code. You just have to get used to them to write effective code rather than trying to force your coding paradigm onto the language, I'm afraid.

Comment: You will want to remove portions inside-out. So for instance: see what Flatten does, then see what `Norm[#]^2 & /@ Flatten[pos, 1]` leaves you with, then the need for Simplify will make sense.

Comment: @Cham You can avoid the lambda calculs (the `#`-`&` notation) by using `\[Function] ` which I find much better readable: `Simplify[
 Map[x \[Function] Norm[x]^2, Flatten[pos, 1]],
 _ \[Element] Reals]`. Copy code snippet to Mathematica and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
Total[pos^2, {-1}]
```

In particular these approaches would allow for vectorization (if pos were a packed array -- which it cannot be if it contains symbols like this one).

The following would be further approaches

```
MapThread[Dot, {#, #}] &@pos

Dot[#, #] & /@ pos
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you, MarcoB!

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I may got the solution to my problem:

```
pos[x_, y_, n_] := Flatten[Table[{x - u, y - v}, {u, -2, 2, 1}, {v, -2, 2, 1}], 1][[n]]

squares[x_, y_, n_] := pos[x, y, n].pos[x, y, n]
```

Not sure yet I'll be able to do everything I need with these...